# Customizing Image toolbar of Dialog in Adobe CQ

Tags: dialog, widget, adobe, toolbar, aem

Has anyone one ever tried to create a new tool in the image toolbar options? For example, the map option in image allows us to create image maps, crop allows us to crop a image. I want to create a replica of map functionality with minor changes such that OOTB map and my functionality could run side by side in a mutually disjoint manner.

Its quite a challenge to decipher OOTB map related JS files. Any help in this regard would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly familiar with the plugin you are looking to customize, but you can relatively easily create custom plugins for the RTE. We have some customizations at https://github.com/Velir/AEM-Toolbox.  Perhaps the more simple plugins here can help guide you to a solution. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: HiSorry i forgot to mention the context. I am talking about dialog customizations for adobe day CQ5.